# NSPredicate Query (KVC) on Collections Containing Collections

Tags: ios, collections, nspredicate, kvc

Edit (I missed a layer of detail):  each teacher has an array of classes. (I ran the JSON through a validator, too, so it's a little easier to read)
Assume the following JSON:

```
{
"schools": [
    {
        "schoolID": "01",
        "schoolName": "School01",
        "teachers": [
            {
                "name": "Mr. Russell",
                "teacherID": "teach01",
                "classes": [
                    {
                        "className": "History",
                        "classID": "class01"
                    },
                    {
                        "className": "Civics",
                        "classID": "class02"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Mrs. Pearl",
                "teacherID": "teach02",
                "classes": [
                    {
                        "className": "English",
                        "classID": "class05"
                    },
                    {
                        "className": "Poetry",
                        "classID": "class06"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "schoolID": "02",
        "schoolName": "School01",
        "teachers": [
            {
                "name": "Mr. Russell",
                "teacherID": "teach05",
                "classes": [
                    {
                        "className": "Pre-Calc",
                        "classID": "class10"
                    },
                    {
                        "className": "Calculus",
                        "classID": "class12"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Mr. Marks",
                "teacherID": "teach07",
                "classes": [
                    {
                        "className": "History",
                        "classID": "class01"
                    },
                    {
                        "className": "Driving",
                        "classID": "class20"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I.e., I have an array of schools, each school contains an array of teachers, and each teacher contains an array of classes. (sorry if the exact formatting of the JSON is not quite right; this is a theoretical model, since I can't divulge the real one, due to NDA requirements.  The actual model is sound.)

I need to run a search on this collection, using NSPredicate & KVC, and get all the classNames called "History".  I've tried to execute it a couple of different ways, but am coming up empty.  For example:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY schools.teachers.classes.className == %@", @"History"];
```

But I'm coming back empty.  Is what I'm attempting too complex for what KVC can execute?  Do I need to iterate through each school and *then* iterate through each teacher, before I can search on the classNames?  Or, if what I want to do is possible, what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try with "LIKE" or "CONTAINS" in this case. But ideally you should create a custom model class which stores all teacher details and then do this search on that.

Comment: Okay, assume I have a Schools object (stored in an array of schools), which contains an array of Teachers objects, which in turn contains an array of Classes objects (see below for update to structure; I missed a beat).  How would I execute a KVC search on that?

Comment: I tried "LIKE", and received the following error: 'Can't do regex matching on object ("-200", "-99", "-100")'.  These are the keys for classID (what I'm actually searching on, in this particular case). In googling that error, it seems regex doesn't like numbers?  How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by

> I need to [...] get all the classNames called "History".

You mean to get the actual classes dictionaries that match the given name.

I believe that your JSON dictionary might be too complex for KVC, but only in the sense that the objects inside the dictionary contain both dictionaries and arrays, so a simple predicate doesn't match just by using the keys.

I was able to get back an array of classes whose name matched "History".  I was able to accomplish this by first creating a single array of classes and then filtering on those.

```
NSDictionary *schoolsDictionary = ...
NSArray *schoolsArray = @[schoolsDictionary];

NSArray *classesArray = [schoolsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.schools.@unionOfArrays.teachers.@unionOfArrays.classes"];
NSArray *filteredClasses = [classesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"className = %@", @"History"]];
```

The result in this case would be

```
(
{
    classID = class01;
    className = History;
},
{
    classID = class01;
    className = History;
}
)
```